# Обновление отрисовки CustomView

Tags: customview, android, java

Сделал `CustomView` для рисования `ProgressBar` и в центре текстом процент от выполненного:

```
public class MyView extends View {

...

public void setRotation(int rotate){
    mRotate = rotate;
}

public int getRotation(){
    return mRotate;
}

public void initCircle(){
    setFocusable(true);
    mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mTextPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(50);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mTextPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    mTextPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    int height = getMeasuredHeight();
    int radius;
    if (width > height) {
        radius = height / 4;
    } else {
        radius = width / 4;
    }

    int center_x, center_y;
    center_x = width / 2;
    center_y = height / 4;
    final RectF oval = new RectF();
    oval.set(center_x - radius, center_y - radius, center_x + radius, center_y + radius);

    center_x = width / 2;
    center_y = height * 3 / 4;
    oval.set(center_x - radius, center_y - radius, center_x + radius, center_y + radius);

    text = String.valueOf(Math.round(360 / (mRotate * 100)));

    canvas.drawText(text + "%", center_x, center_y, mTextPaint);
    canvas.drawArc(oval, -90, mRotate, false, mPaint);

}
}
```

Имею геттер и сеттер на обновление состояния поворота для отрисовки. 
В Activity через `Thread` обновляю поворот `myView.setRotation(count)`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    myView = (MyView)findViewById(R.id.myview);
    myView.setRotation(1);

    Thread thread = new Thread(null, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (myView.getRotation() < 360) {
                count += 2;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        myView.setRotation(count);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

В итоге обновление отрисовки на устройстве не происходит, на эмуляторе отрисовывается, но рывками и только при быстрых нажатиях на экран.
Имею ошибку в создании потока или косяк с `draw()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setRotation(int rotate) должен вызывать invalidate(). Иначе как ваш вью узнает, что он изменился настолько, что нужно перерисоваться?
И второе. Есть метод initCircle, но я не вижу его вызов в конструкторе вью.